# How to create an empty copy of a table in hive

Tags: hive, create-table, hiveddl

I have a table with lots of columns.
I don't want to write something like

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 
table1( 
col1 int, 
col2 String,
etc....)
```

Is there a fast way to create a table with the same structure, but without any data?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this:

```
CREATE TABLE some_db.T1 LIKE some_db.T2
```

See this manual: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-CreateTableLike

Comment: Additionally, you can just show the command that created the table using `SHOW CREATE TABLE <table>`

Comment: additionally， this comand will also create same partition table like the sourse table.